# retrieving gifs from tenor API json

Tags: javascript, json

i'm implementing this `tenor API` into my Site....the thing is that with this function I retrieve a single value `single gif`...How do I `foreach()` all of them?

How would need to be the html structure and the javascript loop

**JAVASCRIPT/ JSON**

```
function grab_data(anon_id)
  {
     // set the apikey and limit
     var apikey = "*************";
     var lmt = 8;

  .....

   // callback for trending top 10 GIFs
     function tenorCallback_trending(responsetext)
    {
       // parse the json response
       var response_objects = JSON.parse(responsetext);

        top_10_gifs = response_objects["results"];

          // load the GIFs -- for our example we will load the first GIFs preview size (nanogif) and share size (tinygif)

      document.getElementById("preview_gif").src = top_10_gifs[1]["media"][0]["nanogif"]["url"];

      document.getElementById("share_gif").src = top_10_gifs[6]["media"][0]["tinygif"]["url"];

     return;

   }
```

I would have this `top_10_gifs` variable loaded of content...how do I foreach it?

**HTML**

```
<h2 class="title">GIF loaded - preview image</h2>
       <div class="container">
      <img id="preview_gif" src="" alt="" style="">
       </div>

        <h2 class="title">GIF loaded - share image</h2>
           <div class="container">
                 <img id="share_gif" src="" alt="" style="">
           </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what exactly you're trying to do (which you haven't explained), but something like

```
response_objects.results.forEach((gifObj, i) => {
  if (i >= 8) return;
  // do something with each gifObj
  document.querySelector('.container')
    .appendChild(document.createElement('img'))
    .src = gifObj.media[0].tinygif.url;
});
```

to iterate over all of them.

Comment: Well, I would only need an iteration to retrieve the basic form "first 8 results"... according to the limit

Comment: That's not set by your `var lmt` at the top there? Well, OK, but the tweak is still easy: the `forEach` parameter function can have an index of the current iteration. Edited answer

Comment: what if I want to retrieve random values from 1 to ..., the first `lmt` numbers?

Comment: Then you iterate while selecting indicies of `Math.random()` multiplied by `lmt`

Comment: ok `var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() *i);`...how should I add this random number within  the object `gifObj` to modify it & make it random..`gifObj[randomNum]` doesnt work